# How to solve series data points do not support values of type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, charts

**This is a two part question**

**First question**

I get data from my database and I want to create a chart of this

I create the chart in my view like this:

```
@{var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
                          .AddTitle("Chart Title")
                          .AddSeries(
                              name: "Employee",
                              xValue: new[] { Model[0].HistoryValues.Select(x => x.LastUpdateSTR).ToList() },
                              yValues: new[] { Model[0].HistoryValues.Select(x=> x.ServerPerformance).ToList()})
                          .Write();
}
```

Error I get:

[image]

This is confusing, Ive tried adding several datetimes manualy like so:

```
 xValue: new[] {DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now },
```

This does work but the dates are obviosly not correct.

**SECOND PART:**

When trying to solve the error above I started experimenting and changed my code to:

```
<div id="Chart col-md-6">
    @{var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
                                .AddTitle("Chart Title")
                                .AddSeries(
                                    name: "Employee",
                                    xValue: new[] {DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now },
                                    yValues: new[] { Model[0].HistoryValues.Select(x=> x.ServerPerformance).ToList()})
                                .Write();
    }
</div>
```

This gave me a weird result. I should be getting 5 bars on the chart but I only got one:

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: What about call `ToArray()` instead `ToList()`?

Comment: And I think you dont need `new[]` part before, because `ToArray()` is already return array :)

Comment: II wrote before reading your second comment...this actually worked. Man I was hoping this was not the answer since it was so simple. Please present it as an answer

Comment: `yValues: Model[0].HistoryValues.Select(x=> x.ServerPerformance).ToArray()` not working?

Comment: Changed the last comment,  
 @Layonez Wronskey kindly present this as an answer and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ToList()` call with `ToArray()` and mabe you have some redundant array initializers in your code